# Ограничение вводимых в базу данных значений

Tags: mysql, база-данных, innodb

Необходимо ограничить вводимые значения в базу данных. Пытался сделать через `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CHECK (columnname > 10)`. Но то ли я что-то делаю неправильно, то ли в базе данных MySql InnoDB не поддерживается эта фича. Осталось два варианта, через триггер ограничить, или просто сделать отдельную таблицу из одного атрибута, и ссылаться из дочерней таблицы на созданную родительскую. Какой вариант лучше? С триггерами мне не нравится, потому что если что, нужно удалять триггер и писать заново, а значения у меня составляют конечное множество (4-5 значений).

Comment: Да, MySQL не поддерживает такие ограничения в принципе, вне зависимости от движка таблиц. Только создавать позволяет "для совместимости". Интересно как вы в варианте со второй таблицей будете записи создавать, вы в нее изначально положите все возможные числа от 10 до бесконечности :) если на лету создавать в ней записи то кто не позволит в нее положить число <10 ? остается триггер ...

Comment: Конечно, для ограничения числовых значений, только остается и триггер. Но я упомянул, что у меня значения из конечного множества (5-6 вариантов, строковое значение). Создавать триггер не охота, так как если появится еще какая то новая запись, то придется удалять триггер, потом добавлять.

Comment: Да, не дочитал до конца. невнимателен. Когда несколько значений я предпочитаю всегда делать таблицу, даже вместо задания check (Я работаю с другой СУБД), так на всякий случай. Только поля типа 'Y', 'N' делаю на check и то один раз пришлось менять такой check потому что кроме Y N появилось третье значение :)

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

Да, MySQL не поддерживает такие ограничения в принципе, вне зависимости от движка таблиц. Только создавать позволяет "для совместимости".

Поэтому остается либо триггер, либо создавать отдельную таблицу, сохраняя в качестве значения либо 'Y', либо 'N'.